# List file that have changed since last commit with GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I need to have the Python script read in the files that have changed since the last Git commit.  Using [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), how would I get the same output as running from cli:

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD
```

I can do something like the following, however, I only need the file names:

```
hcommit = repo.head.commit
for diff_added in hcommit.diff('HEAD~1').iter_change_type('A'):
    print(diff_added)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to pass the `name_only` keyword argument - it would automatically be used as `--name-only` command-line option when a git command would be issued.

The following is the equivalent of `git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD`:

```
diff = repo.git.diff('HEAD~1..HEAD', name_only=True)
print(diff)
```